# Java approach for XML Validation

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, validation, xsd

I want to validate the xml tag values in java.

Scenario:
      Suppose I have data as follow

```
ELements: element1, element2, element3, element4, element5
Values: value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8

Now following are the possible combinations which I have to validate:
  1. Element1 can have value1/value2 ( element1->value1/value2 )
  2. Element2 can have value3/value4 ( element2->value3/value4 )
  4. Element3 can have value5 if element1 has value1 ( element3->value5 if element1->value1 )
     else Element3 can have value6 if element1 has value2 ( element3->value6 if element1->value2 )
  5. Element4 can have value7 if element1->value1 and element2->value4
```

I can have hard-coding of the requirement in one java file but I want a flexible approach wherein if in future any new condition comes into picture then it can be easily added.

I thought of Hibernate Validation but later on came to know that it is supported for Java 6 and above. My constraint is that I have to use Java 1.5

Please suggest an appropriate approach to fulfill the above requirement. Any link suggestion would also work.

Note: Schema validation is already being carried out.

Comment: Besides Schematron, as suggested in one of the answers, you can apply rules using XPath to validate content like that using asserts in XML Schema 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Explore Schematron for applying business rules on XML data

Schematron Project site - http://www.schematron.com

Introduction tutorial - http://www.dpawson.co.uk/schematron/introduction.html,
see for element to element constraints in the tutorial

One more tutorial - http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1318

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html. This has some basic validation techniques i guess assuming you have the schema

Comment: The Validator class is only validating xml against the schema (xsd) but here as I said, schema validation is already done and I am looking out for values validation

Answer (score 0):

use **DOMParser** class in java.
It will help you a lot.